# Can we install dedicated version of apollo graphql in our local machine, if yes what is the procedure to do it

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo

I am working in a client project and we are planing to buy dedicated version of apollo graphql.
Can we install dedicated version of apollo graphql in our local machine, if yes what is the procedure to do it
https://www.apollographql.com/pricing/

I Searched for in internet but couldn't find any website expalaining it, please help

Comment: Seriously: What _answer_ do you expect to get, if you want to know if _you_ can install something on _your_ machine? It's like asking _you_ if _I_ am able to drive my car home and if so, which way I should take.

Answer (score 3):

Apollo's Dedicated offering is currently in private preview and will be GA in the January 2024 timeframe. Apollo's Dedicated Solution is a SaaS solution where Apollo hosts the management plane (Apollo Studio) and the runtime plane (Apollo Router). You connect your graphql client from the application side and your graphql servers for your subgraphs to the Apollo Router.

The main difference between Apollo Serverless, which is GA now, and Apollo Dedicated is that in Serverless the hosted router is in a shared environment, and therefore more suited to development and testing use cases. In Apollo Dedicated you have a dedicated router infrastructure with production SLA's. Dedicated also has advanced router configurations and subgraph security.

Comment: If you are looking on how to run a supergraph locally for development and testing, checkout [Rover Dev](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/rover/commands/dev)! Then when you are ready to deploy, the cloud GraphOS plans for Dedicated can manage your production Router deployment for you